# Export from datatable only selected columns

Tags: javascript, datatable, export, col

I am trying to export a datatable to a excel, pdf and just to copy it.
But i just want to export the selected columns from colvis.
When i am exporting the table, it always shows me the full datatable.
Where is my mistake?

Thx

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tbl').DataTable( {
        dom: 'lBfrtip', 
        language: {
            searchBuilder: {
                button: 'Filter',
            }
        },
        buttons:[
            'searchBuilder',
            {
            extend: 'colvis',
                collectionLayout: 'fixed columns',
                collectionTitle: 'Spalten Auswahl'
            },
            {
            extend: 'copy',
            text: 'Copy',
            exportOptions: {
                modifier: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            }
        }, {
            extend: 'excel',
            text: 'Excel',
            exportOptions: {
                modifier: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            }
        }, 'pdf'        
        ],       
        colReorder: true
        //scrollX: true,
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```js
exportOptions: {
  modifier: {
    columns: ':visible'
  }
}
```

Just use this:

```js
exportOptions: {
  columns: ':visible'
}
```

An example is provided here: [Export options - column selector](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/columns). This is for the `print` button, but it is the same for the [other buttons](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportData()).

> `columns`: The [column selector](https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector) to use. Default - all columns.

The `modifier` option is used to control something different:

> `modifier`: How the ordering and search state of the table should be applied. Default - `{search: 'applied', order: 'applied'}`